# SQL Server (specific) table not updating

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I am having a really strange issue with classic asp insert/update that worked flawlessly for years and was never altered. Out of the blue, the table is no longer updating or taking new records. The code does not throw any errors and the SQL Server log shows no errors either. Other tables in the same database work fine so I can insert and update without issues.

Is there a way to find out what is happening with this table or whether it is locked for some reason. I restarted SQL Server and web application, even the server and no luck.

I updated the table directly in SQL Server and it updates and inserts new records fine.

I used the same code on another table and was able to update records.

Can someone please point me in the right direction as I am out ideas on what may be causing this.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
<%
' *** Edit Operations: (Modified for File Upload) declare variables

Dim MM_editAction
Dim MM_abortEdit
Dim MM_editQuery
Dim MM_editCmd

Dim MM_editConnection
Dim MM_editTable
Dim MM_editRedirectUrl
Dim MM_editColumn
Dim MM_recordId

Dim MM_fieldsStr
Dim MM_columnsStr
Dim MM_fields
Dim MM_columns
Dim MM_typeArray
Dim MM_formVal
Dim MM_delim
Dim MM_altVal
Dim MM_emptyVal
Dim MM_i

MM_editAction = CStr(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))
If (UploadQueryString <> "") Then
  MM_editAction = MM_editAction & "?" & Server.HTMLEncode(UploadQueryString)
End If

' boolean to abort record edit
MM_abortEdit = false

' query string to execute
MM_editQuery = ""
%>

<%
' *** Insert Record: (Modified for File Upload) set variables

If (CStr(UploadFormRequest("MM_insert")) = "update") Then

  MM_editConnection = MM_ar_inventory_STRING
  MM_editTable = "Artists"
  MM_editRedirectUrl = "artists_add.asp?status=ok"
  MM_fieldsStr  = "ArtistName|value|WebsiteStatus|value|Biography|value|Notes|value|ImageFileName|value|ModifiedBy|value|DT|value|IpAddress|value"
  MM_columnsStr = "ARTST_Artist|',none,''|ARTST_WebsiteStatus|',none,''|ARTST_Biography|',none,''|ARTST_Notes|',none,''|ARTST_ArtistImageFileName|',none,''|ARTST_ModifiedBy|',none,''|ARTST_LastModified|',none,NULL|ARTST_LastModifiedIP|',none,''"

  ' create the MM_fields and MM_columns arrays
  MM_fields = Split(MM_fieldsStr, "|")
  MM_columns = Split(MM_columnsStr, "|")

  ' set the form values
  For MM_i = LBound(MM_fields) To UBound(MM_fields) Step 2
    MM_fields(MM_i+1) = CStr(UploadFormRequest(MM_fields(MM_i)))
  Next

  ' append the query string to the redirect URL
  If (MM_editRedirectUrl <> "" And UploadQueryString <> "") Then
    If (InStr(1, MM_editRedirectUrl, "?", vbTextCompare) = 0 And UploadQueryString <> "") Then
      MM_editRedirectUrl = MM_editRedirectUrl & "?" & UploadQueryString
    Else
      MM_editRedirectUrl = MM_editRedirectUrl & "&" & UploadQueryString
    End If
  End If

End If
%>
<%
' *** Insert Record: (Modified for File Upload) construct a sql insert statement and execute it

Dim MM_tableValues
Dim MM_dbValues

If (CStr(UploadFormRequest("MM_insert")) <> "") Then

  ' create the sql insert statement
  MM_tableValues = ""
  MM_dbValues = ""
  For MM_i = LBound(MM_fields) To UBound(MM_fields) Step 2
    MM_formVal = MM_fields(MM_i+1)
    MM_typeArray = Split(MM_columns(MM_i+1),",")
    MM_delim = MM_typeArray(0)
    If (MM_delim = "none") Then MM_delim = ""
    MM_altVal = MM_typeArray(1)
    If (MM_altVal = "none") Then MM_altVal = ""
    MM_emptyVal = MM_typeArray(2)
    If (MM_emptyVal = "none") Then MM_emptyVal = ""
    If (MM_formVal = "") Then
      MM_formVal = MM_emptyVal
    Else
      If (MM_altVal <> "") Then
        MM_formVal = MM_altVal
      ElseIf (MM_delim = "'") Then  ' escape quotes
        MM_formVal = "'" & Replace(MM_formVal,"'","''") & "'"
      Else
        MM_formVal = MM_delim + MM_formVal + MM_delim
      End If
    End If
    If (MM_i <> LBound(MM_fields)) Then
      MM_tableValues = MM_tableValues & ","
      MM_dbValues = MM_dbValues & ","
    End If
    MM_tableValues = MM_tableValues & MM_columns(MM_i)
    MM_dbValues = MM_dbValues & MM_formVal
  Next
  MM_editQuery = "insert into " & MM_editTable & " (" & MM_tableValues & ") values (" & MM_dbValues & ")"

  If (Not MM_abortEdit) Then
    ' execute the insert
    Set MM_editCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection = MM_editConnection
    MM_editCmd.CommandText = MM_editQuery
    MM_editCmd.Execute
    MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection.Close

    If (MM_editRedirectUrl <> "") Then
      Response.Redirect(MM_editRedirectUrl)
    End If
  End If

End If
%>
```

Comment: Without seeing actual code it's going to be pretty hard to help.

Comment: First you have to show us the code that isn't working.

Comment: you can use sql profiler or sql trace to trace the server events and ideally post your code for us to evaluate

Comment: maybe your connection string is different and you're updating the wrong database :)  most folks have dev/staging/production

Comment: JamieD77, I thought about that already and double checked the connection string. Like I mentioned, the code was working fine until my co worker told that they cannot insert or update into the database anymore. The current table has over 2000 records that were inserted and updated using the exact same code.

Comment: Hello there, I updated my post with the code. Like I mentioned, this code worked fine for years and no one edited the code. One day out of the blues, it would not insert or update records.

Comment: You said you're out of ideas so you've obviously debugged. What were the findings? Does it definitely execute the SQL? Is the SQL string set as expected before executing? Have you profiled the database to see the query execute ?

Comment: Alan Macdonald, The redirect happens after the code is executed and I do get redirected to the success page. I used the same code with some tweaks of course to column names on another table and it worked fine. I never used SQL Profiler so I am currently reading some article on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that UploadQueryString is undefined so if you add this as the fist line

```
<%OPTION EXPLICIT%>
```

I guess that you will get some meaningful error messages

Answer (score 0):

The craziest solution to the problem that totally seems unrelated was to disable Symantec Endpoint Protection (Network Protection) and it worked for a reason I cannot possibly explain! Thank you all for the suggestions above.